# Change size of FrameLayout when screen size has been found

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, camera

At the moment I have a FrameLayout which will hold a preview of a picture taken. The size of this is determined in the layout xml file I created for it, at the moment its just set to fill_parent. However the image taken is at 4:3 aspect ratio, but this isn't always going to be the right aspect ratio for the users screen.

For example with my Xperia X10 which is 480 X 854, the 4:3 image taken by the camera always stretches to fit the FrameLayout.

What I want to do is change the size of the FrameLayout outside of the XML file so that it is 4:3 and a size appropriate for the users screen size. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using an ImageView inside your FrameLayout to display the actual picture? In this case, use [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to define how the picture should be stretched.

You can set that in your XML, just use android:scaleType=".." inside your ImageView tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the way my application works is that a Preview class uses the FrameLayout as a holder for the image preview, so it is only a FrameLayout which contains the preview of the image. Can scaleType still be used for FrameLayout aswell?

Comment: Mh I believe not. Maybe I'm missing something, I don't actually understand why you would use a FrameLayout for this kind of task. How do you display the picture? Set it as a background resource for the layout? Or is this actually something entirely different, like a camera preview?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain it very well. Yes the FrameLayout is being used as the camera preview, not just to preview the image taken, there may well be a much easier way to do it however this is the way I found that worked.

Comment: Ah ok. Just to clearify that a bit more before I try to answer that: The camera preview is usually a SurfaceView. So we are dealing with a SurfaceView inside a FrameLayout?

Comment: No, my xml is simply a FrameLayout inside a LinearLayout, is SurfaceView a better option?

Comment: I'm sorry i have to ask this much, but it's very confusing. If this is a live camera preview (basically a video of the cameras view), you have to use a SurfaceView to display that data (see the camera preview example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html). Or are you grabbing single preview frames from the preview callback and display those?

Comment: Right I'll try and explain my code, first of I have a PhotoCapture activity, this is the Activity which has the FrameLayout and displays the preview, this also initialises a new Preview. My Preview class extends SurfaceView and contains all the code for when the surface is created destroyed and changed, it also contains the  code for actually taking a picture. When a button is clicked the PhotoCapture activity is called and it shows a preview while autofocussing, then shows the picture that was taken.

Comment: Ahh. In this case i really recommend that sample i posted above. There is a function getOptimalPreviewSize() that does calculate the optimal preview resolution, depending on the devices display resolution/aspectratio. The sample basically reads the supported preview sizes and the display size, feeds that function with it, and sets the result as the preview resolution. But if you want to fix the ratio to 4:3, it gets a bit complicated (i tried to archieve that while ago, if you are interested, ill post that as a seperate answer).

Comment: Well what I need to do is to preview the taken image with the correct width and height. How would the getOptimalPreviewSize go about doing this, I think its just a matter of changing the size of the FrameLayout, or changing something with the holder maybe in the Preview class that extends SurfaceView. As far as the example you posted above goes, I dont have an ImageView to scale. What do you think?

Comment: Okay I've had a look at the CameraPreview example. I assume the way it changes the size of the preview is by using parameters.setPreviewSize(....)? If this is the case, it doesn't work for me, even setting it to (50, 50) still makes the preview fill the screen, do I need to set any scaling options within the class or on the FrameLayout?

Comment: @alextsc let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1737/discussion-between-william-stewart-and-alextsc)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Framelayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
 lv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Try using the above code...

Comment: I did try this, however it always seems to result in the application crashing, or it throws a nullpointer exception.